# How can you find the size of a datatype without creating a variable or pointer, or using sizeof of the datatype?

Tags: c

The question shown below is an interview question:

Q) You are given/have a datatype, say X in C.

The requirement is to get the size of the datatype, without declaring a
variable or a pointer variable of that type,

And of course, without using sizeof operator !

I am not sure if this question has already been asked on SO.

Thanks and regards
Maddy

Comment: If I answer it, do I get the job?

Comment: @Oded-I am not sure what to answer for that.Y dont u post this question in this forum and get the answers for that,thats better i guess.

Comment: I guess the correct answer is "always use sizeof!"

Comment: @modosansreves ---The question  also tells that not even use the sizeof operator

Comment: Interesting C language question, but definitely shouldn't be asked during any interview imho. Unless they want to hire some c cowboy hackers :/

Comment: if you are asked this question in an interview you should pull the rip cord and bail out lest you be doomed to work under Dwight K Schrute for the rest of your life...

Comment: What kind of weirdos are interviewing programmers these days?

Comment: @maddy: Is there a reason you changed the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can typecast 0 (or any arbitrary value) to type datatype X* to find the size of the datatype, just like the below example:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    struct node{
        char c;
        int i;
    };

    int main()
    {
        printf("Sizeof node is: %d\n", ((char *)((struct node *)0 + 1) - (char *)((struct node *)0)));   
// substract 2 consecutive locations starting from 0 that point to type node, 
//typecast these values to char * to give the value in number of bytes.
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Bravo!! super way of finding the size

Comment: To expand on R..'s comment: computing with invalid pointers such as `NULL` is not guaranteed to work (even if you don't attempt to dereference them) ([see also the discussion on Frank Bollack's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2817559#2817559). It works on many common machines, but not all.

Answer (score 17):

## define sizeof_type( type )  (size_t)((type*)1000 + 1 )-(size_t)((type*)1000)

The original is from this discussion.
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-to-know-the-size-of-the-variable-without-using-sizeof-469920/

Comment: easy enough - although the 1000 is confusing; can't we just use 0?

Comment: To expand on R..'s comment: computing with invalid pointers such as `NULL` is not guaranteed to work (even if you don't attempt to dereference them) ([see also the discussion on Frank Bollack's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2817559#2817559). It works on many common machines, but not all.

Answer (score 16):

This should do the trick:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
   int i;
   short j;
   char c[5];

} X;

int main(void)
{
   size_t size = (size_t)(((X*)0) + 1);
   printf("%lu", (unsigned long)size);

   return 0;
}
```

**Explanation of `size_t size = (size_t)(((X*)0) + 1);`**

- assuming  a `sizeof(X)` would return 12 (`0x0c`) because of alignment
- `((X*)0)` makes a pointer of type `X` pointing to memory location 0 (`0x00000000)`
- `+ 1` increments the pointer by the the size of one element of type `X`, so pointing to `0x0000000c`
- the expression `(size_t)()` casts the address, that is given by the expression `(((X*)0) + 1)` back to an integral type (`size_t`)

Hope that gives some insight.

Comment: Actually, the main point in this site is to explain how things work: The way people learn is not by having an answer told to them, it's by having it EXPLAINED.

Comment: @Frank Bollack...What does this line mean in the program of yours?size_t size = (size_t)(((X*)0) + 1); in the main function.

Comment: @Frank..Thanks a lot for that.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic on invalid pointers yields undefined behaviour (as does 'void main' and using the wrong printf conversion specifier).

Comment: @Frank No problem, -1 retracted :) I'd upvote now but the slightly bizarre voting rules don't let me.

Comment: Beside the undefined behaviour, a NULL pointer is not guaranteed to have all bits 0. An implementation is even allowed to have different NULL pointer representations for different types.

Comment: @fizzer: fixed most issues, but can you give a reference for your first statement.

Comment: I don't have the Standard to hand for chapter & verse, but see the discussion of invalid pointers in the Rationale http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf

Comment: @fizzure:  Pointer arithmetic is valid for an invalid pointer (pointer with an *invalid* value).  When adding or subtracting from a pointer, there is no check of validity.  Validity is checked when the pointer is dereferenced.

Comment: @Thomas: No, even reading the value of an invalid pointer is already undefined behaviour. See page 49 in the link fizzer gave: "Regardless how an invalid pointer is created, any use of it yields undefined behavior." And from the Standard, Annex J.2: "The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances: [...]The value of a pointer to an object whose lifetime has ended is used (6.2.4)." *Used*, not dereferenced.

Comment: The rationale even specifies exactly one situation where pointer arithmetic on an invalid pointer might cause a crash: On a segmented architecture, the runtime can look at the segment descriptor table to figure out what the resulting pointer of the addition should be. For invalid pointers, that won't exist, and crash.

Here's a little more commentary on the same lines: http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2010/04/good-math-bad-pointer-math.html

Answer (score 4):

Declare a structure with a member of that type, then use offsetof to compute the size?

```
struct outer
{
     X x;
     char after;
};
```

`offsetof(outer, after)` should give you the (aligned) size of x. Note that I'm not declaring a variable of that type per se, nor a pointer to the type, but I'm including it as a member of a structure declaration, where I measure the location of the member that comes after it.

The offsetof macro can be defined as

```
#define offsetof(S, f) ((size_t)(&((S *)0)->f))
```

Comment: "without declaring a variable or a pointer variable of that type" ?

Comment: @John Källén-Can you please give me a better explanation for that?
I am not clear with the answer.

Comment: I argue that here X is not used a variable, because memory for X is not allocated.

Comment: The offsetof macro computes the offset of a member within a structure. If I compute the offset of 'after' in the structure 'outer', I get the number of bytes that are "before" it in that structure. This should be the same as the size of X, with some possible bytes added for alignment. Actually, changing the int to a char would alleviate the alignment constraint.

Comment: @John Källén...Thanks a lot.Infact i was not sure about the offsetof macro used.

Comment: +1 for only answer that meets the requirements and doesn't invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm a bit worried about if the offset of `after` is required to be the size of `x`, though. How about: `struct outer { X x[2]; };` and then use `offsetof(struct outer, x[1])`?

Comment: @R.. You're right to be worried. John: the `offsetof` macro is provided by the standard library. While what you show is a common implementation, there are platforms where it won't work, and you can't (reasonably) define `offsetof` in your own program (name clash).

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%d",(int)(&x+1)-(int)&x
```

Comment: for gnu compiler and tc++ both