# Alternate way of computing size of a type using pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, c, pointers, portability, casting

Is the following code 100% portable?

```
int a=10;
size_t size_of_int = (char *)(&a+1)-(char*)(&a); // No problem here?

std::cout<<size_of_int;// or printf("%zu",size_of_int);
```

**P.S**: The question is only for learning purpose. So please don't give answers like `Use sizeof()` etc

Comment: portable to what? int is not platform independent and has a different meaning in 64bit systems. Although my c++ is probably too rusty for this.

Comment: @Blub: I mean will the above always code print sizeof(int) (eg: 4 on a typical 32 bit environment)?

Comment: for the records, could you please chose an appropriate title for your question? something that at least mentions pointer arithmetic. thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From ANSI-ISO-IEC 14882-2003, p.87 (c++03):

> "75) Another way to approach pointer
>   arithmetic is first to convert the
>   pointer(s) to character pointer(s): In
>   this scheme the integral value of the
>   expression added to or subtracted from
>   the converted pointer is first
>   multiplied by the size of the object
>   originally pointed to, and the
>   resulting pointer is converted back to
>   the original type. For pointer
>   subtraction, the result of the
>   difference between the character
>   pointers is similarly divided by the
>   size of the object originally pointed
>   to."

This seems to suggest that the pointer difference equals to the object size.

If we remove the UB'ness from incrementing a pointer to a scalar a and turn a into an array:

```
int a[1];
size_t size_of_int = (char*)(a+1) - (char*)(a);

std::cout<<size_of_int;// or printf("%zu",size_of_int);
```

Then this looks OK. The clauses about alignment requirements are consistent with the footnote, if alignment requirements are always divisible by the size of the object.

**UPDATE:** Interesting. As most of you probably know, GCC allows to specify an explicit alignment to types as an extension. But I can't break OP's "sizeof" method with it because GCC refuses to compile it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int a8_int __attribute__((aligned(8)));

int main()
{
 a8_int v[2];

 printf("=>%d\n",((char*)&v[1]-(char*)&v[0]));
}
```

The message is `error: alignment of array elements is greater than element size`.

Comment: If you replace `&a[1]` with `&a[0]+1` or `a+1`, an array of size 1 suffices, because it is legal to point one-past-the-end of an array. Also, you should replace `&[0]` with `&a[0]` or `a` ;-)

Comment: +1 for technically correct answer. 

@FredOverflow:In C99 `&a[1]` and `a+1` are just the same. :)

Comment: @Prasoon: Yes, but C++ is not C99, and I prefer a solution that works in both languages.

Comment: is `sizeof(char)==1` guaranteed by the standard ? if not, then this might not be 100% portable.

Comment: @smerlin: `is sizeof(char)==1 guaranteed by the standard ?` Yes.

Comment: 5.3.3-1 [expr.sizeof] : "sizeof(char), sizeof(signed char) and sizeof(unsigned char) are 1;".

Answer (score 4):

<strike>`&a+1` will lead to undefined behavior according to the C++ Standard 5.7/5:</strike>

> When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of
>   the pointer operand. <...> If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined**.

`&a+1` is OK according to 5.7/4:

> For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to a nonarray object behaves the same as a pointer to the first
>   element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type.

That means that 5.7/5 can be applied without UB. And finally remark 75 from 5.7/6 as `@Luther Blissett` noted in his answer says that the code in the question is valid.

---

In the production code you should use `sizeof` instead. But the C++ Standard doesn't guarantee that `sizeof(int)` will result in 4 on every 32-bit platform.

Comment: It is IMHO valid as per

`If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object,...`

The `&a+1` pointer points one past the end which is valid and usable pointer.

Comment: You should replace `&a[1]` with `&a[0]+1` or `a+1`, because the former may lead to [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144904/may-i-take-the-address-of-the-one-past-the-end-element-of-an-array-closed).

Answer (score 2):

No. This code won't work as you expect on every plattform. At least in theory, there might be a plattform with e.g. 24 bit integers (=3 bytes) but 32 bit alignment. Such alignments are not untypical for (older or simpler) plattforms. Then, your code would return 4, but sizeof( int ) would return 3.

But I am not aware of a real hardware that behaves that way. In practice, your code will work on most or all plattforms.

Comment: -1, on such platforms `sizeof(int)` is 4. However, 8 of those 32 bits will not take part in the value representation of the int. Only for (unsigned) char do you get the guarantee that all bits participate in the value representation. (Has to, else you couldn't memcpy things).

Answer (score 2):

It's not 100% portable for the following reasons:

1. Edit: You'd best use `int a[1];` and then `a+1` becomes definitively valid.
2. &a invokes undefined behaviour on objects of register storage class.
3. In case of alignment restrictions that are larger or equal than the size of `int` type, `size_of_int` will not contain the correct answer.

## Disclaimer:

I am uncertain if the above hold for C++.

Comment: +1 for note about UB & register.  Though if you're using register (for good reasons), you certainly know about sizeof and any related portability concerns.

Comment: It's never UB. In C it's ill-formed (diagnostic required) and in C++ it's allowed (sicne compilers ignored it anyway).

Comment: @MSalters: I assume you were talking about (1)? It, in fact, - after actually referring to the standard - according to the semantics for additive operators is indeed OK. I cannot find where it's considered as ill-formed. Can you help?

Comment: sorry, I responded to Drew Hall's comment, which commented on the UB assumed in (2).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
size_t size_of_int = sizeof(int);
```

Comment: That does not answer my question. I know we have the `sizeof()` operator for such purpose. The question is just for learning purpose. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is probably implementation defined.

I can imagine a (hypothetical) system where sizeof(int) is smaller than the default alignment.

It looks only safe to say that `size_of_int >= sizeof(int)`

Answer (score 0):

The code above will portably compute `sizeof(int)` on a target platform but the latter is implementation defined - you will get different results on different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it gives you the equivalent of `sizeof(a)` but using `ptrdiff_t` instead of `size_t` type.

Answer (score 0):

There was a debate on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817455/an-interview-question).

See the comments on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817455/an-interview-question/2817559#2817559) to that question for some pointers at why this is not only non-portable, but also is undefined behaviour by the standard.