# size of struct without use sizeof keyword

Tags: c++

here is code which returns  size of struct without   using sizeof keyword

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct  point{
    int x;
    int y;
    };
struct point pt={0,0};

int main(){
    point *ppt=&pt;
    unsigned char *p1,*p2;
    p1=(unsigned char *)ppt;
    p2=(unsigned char *)++ppt;
    printf("%d",p2-p1);


     return 0;
}
```

it returns 8 as i understand because  sizeof char is 1 byte  and this struct   contains integer  types first it convers it to char using char   pointers and returns sizeof char? or?i dont understand exactly how it works
thanks

Comment: As pointed out in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387021/portability-of-the-code the code results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Neil: Where exactly is the undefined bevahior? I don't see it. `++ppt` is legal as long as the resulting pointer isn't dereferenced.

Comment: @Fred p2 is not a valid pointer, for the reasons discussed in the question I referenced.

Comment: @Neil: Did you read 5.7 §4? "a pointer to a nonarray object behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type" Thus it *is* legal to obtain `&pt+1` as long as you don't dereference it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cast here happens after the ++

```
p2 = (unsigned char *)++ppt;
```

It works because ++ on a pointer increases the pointer the number of bytes equal to the size of the type pointed to.  Then you cast to char, because minus divides the difference in pointers by the size of the type (so divide by 1 because it's now char*).

One caveat if you plan to use this -- sizeof is definitely done at compile time where this code may or may not be recognized by the optimizer as being a constant expression.

Also, as pointed out by the commenter and other question, it won't match sizeof if the type needs alignment (some systems require that types start on memory boundaries divisible by 2, 4, etc).

Finally, (from the comments), once the pointer has been incremented, it is invalid and cannot be used (even for subtracting, comparison -- i.e. even in ways that don't dereference it)

**From the C Rationale Document:** http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf

> Implicit in the Standard is the notion
>   of invalid pointers. In discussing
>   pointers, the Standard typically
>   refers to “a pointer to an object” or
>   “a pointer to a function” or “a null
>   pointer.” A special case in address
>   arithmetic allows for a pointer to
>   just past the end of an array. Any
>   other pointer is invalid.
>
> An invalid pointer might be created in
>   several ways. An arbitrary value can
>   be assigned (via a cast) to a pointer
>   variable. (This could even create a
>   valid pointer, depending on the
>   value.) A pointer to an object becomes
>   invalid if the memory containing the
>   object is deallocated or moved by
>   realloc. Pointer arithmetic can
>   produce pointers outside the range of
>   an array.
>
> Regardless how an invalid pointer is
>   created, any use of it yields
>   undefined behavior. Even assignment,
>   comparison with a null pointer
>   constant, or comparison with itself,
>   might on some systems result in an
>   exception.
>
> Consider a hypothetical segmented
>   architecture on which pointers
>   comprise a segment descriptor and an
>   offset. Suppose that segments are
>   relatively small so that large arrays
>   are allocated in multiple segments.
>   While the segments are valid
>   (allocated, mapped to real memory),
>   the hardware, operating system, or C
>   implementation can make these multiple
>   segments behave like a single object:
>   pointer arithmetic and relational
>   operators use the defined mapping to
>   impose the proper order on the
>   elements of the array. Once the memory
>   is deallocated, the mapping is no
>   longer guaranteed to exist. Use of the
>   segment descriptor might now cause an
>   exception, or the hardware addressing
>   logic might return meaningless data.

Comment: After incrementing ppt, it no longer points to a valid object. Any use of ppt afterwards results in undefined behaviour. This is probably the fifth time this type of question has been discussed today. :/

Comment: "fifth time this type of question has been discussed today" - do I smell like a stupid homework assignment? ;)

Comment: @msw: either that, or an interview. :-)

Comment: @mfukar You can't dereference it, but you can use the value of the pointer.  If not, things like .end() in the STL wouldn't work.

Comment: @Lou end() works with arrays, where you are allowed one past the end - there is no array in the OP's code.

Comment: Arrays aren't actually needed: `int a; (&a) + 1;` is technically valid too. It's also a pointer immediately past an object. ISTR this has been clarified after 1998 (C++ standard) and wasn't explicit in C89.

Comment: Ahh -- correct.  Just updated with the appropriate part from the standard

Comment: ok -- I'm not sure what the right answer is -- if someone has a definitive source, please update the answer.  In any case, with things this subtle, where experts debate the standard -- BEST TO NOT DEPEND ON IT.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct  ABC{
    int a;
    float b;
    char c;
};
int main(){
    struct ABC *ptr=(struct ABC *)0;
    ptr++;
    printf("Size of structure is: %d",*ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

This is an alternate way to find size of `struct` without using `sizeof`.

Comment: This actually gives a segmentation fault, you should not deference the ptr rather just point to the location after 0th address.